# Synchronized in Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, keyword, synchronized

I have three synchronized methods in a class when i try to execute all of them by starting different threads, I am unable to see the synchronized output, no lock is obtained on object  & i could see in output all the threads are executed simultaneously. Below is my code. Inputs are appreciated. Thanks

public class DisplayMessage {

```
public static synchronized void sayHello(String name) throws InterruptedException{
    for(int i=1; i<=10;i++){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("How are you"+name);
    }
}
public synchronized void sayHello1(String name2,int j){
    for(int i=1; i<=10;i++){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("How are you Hello1  :: "+name2+ " Age " + j);
    }
}
public synchronized void sayHello2(String name3,String lastname){
    for(int i=1; i<=10;i++){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("How are you Hello 2 :: "+ name3 + " lastname " +lastname);
    }
}
```

}
Thread class :

public class MyThread extends Thread {

```
String name;


MyThread(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}

public void run() {

    try {
        DisplayMessage.sayHello(name);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}
Thread2 class :
public class MyThread2 extends Thread {

```
String name2;
String name3;

int age;
DisplayMessage dm;

MyThread2(DisplayMessage dm, String name2, int age) {
    this.dm = dm;
    this.name2 = name2;
    this.age = age;
}

public void run() {

    dm.sayHello1(name2, age);

}
```

}
Thread3 class:

package Synchronization.classlock;

public class MyThread3 extends Thread {

```
String name3;
String lastname;
int age;

DisplayMessage dm2;

MyThread3(DisplayMessage dm, String name3, String lastname) {
    this.dm2 = dm;
    this.name3 = name3;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public void run() {

    dm2.sayHello2(name3, lastname);
}
```

}

Democlass with main method spawning different threads
public class SynchronizationDemo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DisplayMessage dm=new DisplayMessage();
    MyThread t1= new MyThread("steve");
    MyThread t2=new MyThread("Anitha");
    MyThread2 t3=new MyThread2(dm," Amit", 31);
    MyThread3 t4=new MyThread3(dm," Arit ","urkude");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();

}
```

}

below are the outputs:

How are yousteve
How are you Hello1  ::  Amit Age 31
How are you Hello1  ::  Amit Age 31
How are yousteve
How are yousteve
How are you Hello1  ::  Amit Age 31
How are yousteve
How are you Hello1  ::  Amit Age 31
How are yousteve
How are you Hello1  ::  Amit Age 31
How are yousteve
How are you Hello1  ::  Amit Age 31
How are yousteve
How are you Hello1  ::  Amit Age 31
How are you Hello1  ::  Amit Age 31
How are yousteve
How are yousteve
How are you Hello1  ::  Amit Age 31
How are yousteve
How are you Hello1  ::  Amit Age 31
How are youAnitha
How are you Hello 2 ::  Arit  lastname urkude
How are youAnitha
How are you Hello 2 ::  Arit  lastname urkude
How are youAni
How are you Hello 2 ::  Arit  lastname urkude
How are youAni
How are you Hello 2 ::  Arit  lastname urkude
How are you Hello 2 ::  Arit  lastname urkude
How are youAni
How are youAni
How are you Hello 2 ::  Arit  lastname urkude
How are youAni
How are you Hello 2 ::  Arit  lastname urkude
How are you Hello 2 ::  Arit  lastname urkude
How are youAni
How are youAni
How are you Hello 2 ::  Arit  lastname urkude
How are youAni
How are you Hello 2 ::  Arit  lastname urkude

Comment: You are synchornizing on a static method as well as 2 instance methods, is that what you want?. Why not use just one method and see how synchronized works

Answer (score 2):

The output you are seeing is perfectly valid according to your code. `MyThread` is using `DisplayMessage.sayHello()` method, which is `static` and therefore synchronized on the `DisplayMessage.class` object. Usage of `synchronized` keyword on `static` method is equivalent to:

```
public static void sayHello(String name) throws InterruptedException{
    synchronized(DisplayMessage.class) {
        for(int i=1; i<=10;i++){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("How are you"+name);
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand two other threads, `MyThread2` and `MyThread3` are calling non-static methods - `sayHello1` and `sayHello2`, which are synchronized on `this`. Usage of `synchronized` keyword in this case is equivalent to:

```
public void sayHello1(String name2,int j){
    synchronized(DisplayMessage.this) {
        for(int i=1; i<=10;i++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("How are you Hello1  :: "+name2+ " Age " + j);
        }
    }
}
```

So, your output contains `steve` and `Amit` running concurently followed by `Anitha` and `Arit` running concurently, which is expected as code is synchronized on two different objects.

Comment: Thanks  for explanation

Answer (score 1):

synchronized keyword added to the static method is to the current *.java file corresponding to the class lock; and synchronized keyword added to the no-static method is to this object lock. Although the two locks are different, but this object lock and class lock can be re-entered each other.